# The transaction ended in the trigger. The batch has been aborted

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, database

Get error mail

The transaction ended in the trigger. The batch has been aborted.

The trigger code:

```
ALTER TRIGGER [dbo].[trgAfterInsertUpdate_DRSDetails] ON [dbo].[TT_DR_Details]
--AFTER INSERT, UPDATE
AFTER UPDATE
AS
BEGIN
-- SET XACT_ABORT ON will cause the transaction to be uncommittable 
SET XACT_ABORT ON

BEGIN TRY
    DECLARE @tempDRDetail_CNote TABLE
    (
        ConsignmentNo   VARCHAR(20),
        Form_type       VARCHAR(5),
        DeliverStatus   VARCHAR(50),
        Reason          VARCHAR(250),
        Remark          VARCHAR(150),
        AreaId          VARCHAR(10),
        EmpId           INT,
        BranchId        INT
    )

    DELETE FROM @tempDRDetail_CNote

    INSERT INTO @tempDRDetail_CNote
    (
        ConsignmentNo
        ,Form_type
        ,DeliverStatus
        ,Reason
        ,Remark
        ,AreaId
        ,EmpId
        ,BranchId
    )
    SELECT
        INS.Cnote
        ,INS.Form_type
        ,INS.DeliverStatus
        ,INS.Reason
        ,INS.Remark
        ,DRM.Area_id
        ,DRM.Emp_Id
        ,DRM.Branch_id
    FROM Inserted INS
    INNER JOIN dbo.TT_DR_Master DRM WITH(READUNCOMMITTED)
    ON INS.Ref_DR_Id = DRM.DR_Id

    UPDATE CA
    SET
        CA.ModifiedOn = GETDATE()
        ,CA.ConsignmentType = INS.Form_type
        ,CA.AlertStatus = 0
        ,CA.ConsignmentStatus = CASE INS.DeliverStatus
                                    WHEN 'Un-Delivered' THEN INS.DeliverStatus + ', Reason: ' + INS.Reason + ', Remark: ' + INS.Remark
                                    WHEN 'Delivered' THEN INS.DeliverStatus --+ ', ' + INS.RecBy
                                    WHEN 'Out For Delivery' THEN INS.DeliverStatus + ', Area Name: ' + ARM.AreaName + ', Delivery Boy: ' + AG.AgentName
                                END
    FROM dbo.SK_Opt_ConsignmentAlert CA WITH(READUNCOMMITTED)
    INNER JOIN @tempDRDetail_CNote INS
    ON CA.ConsignmentNo = INS.ConsignmentNo
    INNER JOIN dbo.TT_AreaMaster ARM WITH(READUNCOMMITTED)
    ON INS.AreaId = ARM.AR_ID AND INS.BranchId = ARM.Branch_ID
    INNER JOIN dbo.AgentMaster AG WITH(READUNCOMMITTED)
    ON INS.EmpId = AG.Agent_ID AND INS.BranchId = AG.BranchId
    WHERE
    ISNULL(CA.IsDMStatus, 0) = 0
END TRY

BEGIN CATCH
 --  IF (@@TRANCOUNT > 0)
    --ROLLBACK TRANSACTION

    -- Test XACT_STATE:  
        -- If 1, the transaction is committable.  
        -- If -1, the transaction is uncommittable and should   
        --     be rolled back.  
        -- XACT_STATE = 0 means that there is no transaction and  
        --     a commit or rollback operation would generate an error.  

    -- Test whether the transaction is uncommittable.  
    IF (XACT_STATE()) = -1  
    BEGIN  
        ROLLBACK TRANSACTION
    END  

    -- Test whether the transaction is committable.  
    IF (XACT_STATE()) = 1  
    BEGIN  
        COMMIT TRANSACTION
    END

    --SELECT CAST(ERROR_NUMBER() AS VARCHAR) + ' - ' + ERROR_MESSAGE() AS ErrorMessage

    INSERT INTO dbo.FK_Opt_ExceptionLog
    (
        APIName
        ,ExceptionMessage
        ,ExceptionTrace
        ,ExceptionMachineIP
        ,CreatedBy
        ,CreatedOn
        ,SourceId
    )
    SELECT
        'trgAfterInsertUpdate_DRSDetails'
        ,CAST(ERROR_NUMBER() AS VARCHAR) + ' - ' + ERROR_MESSAGE()
        ,''
        ,''
        ,'KOLKA-ADMIN'
        ,GETDATE()
        ,5
END CATCH
END
```

Comment: The problem is probably near `dbo.`. If you want a more specific location, try to create a [mcve].

Comment: Do u mean                                                                                            
ALTER TRIGGER [dbo].[trgAfterInsertUpdate_DRSDetails] ON [dbo].[TT_DR_Details]

Or whole page.

Comment: You really don't want to have transaction management inside a trigger. It will do nothing but cause you problems. If your calling code starts a transaction the trancount will be off when it gets back to your code or even worse you roll it back inside the trigger and there is no transaction for your calling code anymore. Let errors happen inside triggers so that applications can handle them.

Comment: Slight detour: using READUNCOMMITTED everywhere is a bad habit and should never be used inside a trigger. It is far more sinister than simply dirty reads (keep in mind that the trigger can see the changes inside the transaction that it is involved with). That hint is the same thing as NOLOCK. https://blogs.sentryone.com/aaronbertrand/bad-habits-nolock-everywhere/